# rails insert ajax via jquery

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Good day!
I'm trying to implement ajax in my rails test app.
my controller code app/controllers/admin/data

```
class Admin::DataController < ApplicationController
...  
  def ajax
   if  params[:ajax] == 'list'
 @responce = Admin::Datum.all
   else
     @responce ={error: true}
   end
    respond_to do |format|
      # format.html { redirect_to @user }
      # format.js
      format.json { render json: @responce }
    end
  end
    end
```

index.js.erb

```
alert('1');
$.post('/admin/data/ajax',{ajax:'list'},function(responce){
alert('2');
console.log(responce);
}
);
```

could you help me in determining the url that i've to use in ajax to access ajax method?
or any other help is very welcome!

**Update 1
Updated initial code to represent more complex problem**

Comment: Is the request is post request also It seem that you haven't specified the dataType for the request. as per route show us your route.rb

Comment: It works perfectly fine without it. I presume because of format.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added to routes.rb

```
 match 'admin/data/ajax' => 'Admin::Data#ajax'
```

could be any url, it's what you write in your jquery.
And it works!